# Exception Handler for Ktor

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, ktor

I tried to code a Web Application. I want so send the Exceptions of the Programm to a Notification System, but with setting the UncaughtExceptionHandler, i didnt get the Exceptions thrown in Ktor Routing and by Ktor.

Is there anyone who know how to set a handler for all exceptions even if there handled or not?

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible. On the Ktor side, you can use the `StatusPages` plugin https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html to catch exceptions and send information about them to the notification system.

Comment: So it's impossible to catch all Stacktraces with Java? Is there a function in Logback which allows me to set a handler for Stacktraces?